# Send data from DB to client(front) in stream mode

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function what get some data from DB and I don't know how to send it to the front in stream mode.

**Example:**

```
    async (req, res) => {
      const data = await getData(req.query.id);
 // below I want to pipe data from result of function **getData()** to **res**
      data.pipe(res);
    },
```

Comment: What result or error are you getting? What's the return value of `getData`? It has to be a Stream object.

Comment: getData() - return a big string